# How to prove that a functor factors through another functor under some certain conditions

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal C$ be an additive category, $B$ and $L$ two objects in $\mathcal C$, and $G$ a functor $\mathcal C^{op} \to \mathsf{Ab}$. Suppose there are morphisms
$$\alpha \colon \hom_{\mathcal C}(-,B) \to G,\qquad  
\beta \colon \hom_{\mathcal C}(-,L) \to G$$
such that $\operatorname{Im}\alpha \subset \operatorname{Im}\beta$.

My goal is to prove that there is a morphism $\gamma \colon \hom_{\mathcal C}(-,L) \to \hom_{\mathcal C}(-,B)$ satisfying $\beta=\alpha\gamma$.

Maybe should I use Yoneda's lemma in here?

Comment: Something isn't right: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are morphisms from functors $\mathcal C^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathsf{Ab}$ to a functor $G \colon \mathcal C \to \mathsf{Ab}$... For consistency, $G$ should be contravariant.

Comment: @Pece I have corrected the statement, do you have some ideas about this？ THANK YOU.

Comment: Yes, use the Yoneda lemma.

Comment: could you tell me some details please? @Zhen Lin